# How to share lambda function with another user in organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

My company is new to AWS and I've been piloting a development effort to build a lambda function. I've finished my coding and I need to hand it off to another team.  How can I allow another team member to access/run/execute/develop/etc... the lambda function from their account?

Comment: Does the other team have access to the same AWS account? How can you identify the "team"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want them to invoke the Lambda cross account, which was your original question, then you can [delegate access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) to an IAM user (or all users) in the other AWS account so that they can assume a role in your account and invoke the Lambda function in your account.

Technically, you could just add IAM users to your account and give them credentials, but that is not a best practice. Cross-account roles are preferred.

But is this really what you want? It would not allow them, for example, to update the Lambda function. You need to think about what their responsibilities will be. If they are going to maintain the Lambda function then it's more likely that they should deploy the Lambda function into their account and you give their Lambda function cross-account access to whichever resources it needs in your AWS account.

If you want to share development then use a shared code repo (like GitHub or CodeCommit) and create a process, automated or otherwise, for packaging and uploading the Lambda function to your account. Again, they may need to be able to assume a cross-account IAM role in order to update and/or invoke your Lambda function.

At a higher level, if what you’re building here is actually a serverless application with an API, then consider using the serverless framework or AWS SAM, with API Gateway, for development, packaging, and deployment.

On your question about account structure, this is taking us far from the original question, so I'd recommend further reading, for example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/cost-optimization-laying-the-foundation/aws-account-structure.html) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6ajxni/aws_environment_for_dev_stage_and_prod_opinions/). There are plenty of opinions on account strategy, some of which may be a good match depending on your needs.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be able to modify the function as well as them.  Is that possible? I actually was working on that exact article, but I figured there had to be an easier way.  If I'm on linux and want to do that I just add a new user add add them to the group that can modify the code in a specific directory.  I'm a bit taken back that it's so complicated to do this. It's pretty common that you would have multiple developers working on one piece of code.

Comment: You don’t (should not) modify code in Lambda. You modify code in git (say, GitHub or CodeCommit to which you both have access) then you set up a simple CI/CD pipeline to deploy that code out to Lambda.

Comment: ok, this is probably the problem.  I am developing in the lambda (like I said I'm new to this).  Any recommendations on CI/CD pipeline tech stacks? I was trying to use pycharm to pull down lambdas, develop them and push them back up.

Comment: Assuming that you are using Python, I would take a look at Chalice (https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It has CD options (https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/cd.html).

Comment: so is it standard practice to create separate accounts in an aws organization for each developer as well as a production and test account?  Then when the development is ready for test you deploy code to test and the same for prod?

Comment: It's atypical to create an account per developer, in my experience (if by developer, you mean a single person). It's common to see prod, dev, and test accounts (possibly one set dedicated to a product, if it's large enough, but often shared). Have added to original answer.